# tomcat-webapp not accessible via port after windows-update

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat, hyper-v, port

we are running 4 Virtual Machines on a MS HyperV Host.

On one of the VMs (192.168.50.15) we have multiple Tomcat-Webapps on separate ports - 9010: Jenkins - 9020: Atlassian Jira - 9030: Wiki ..

These Apps are all accessible locally from the VM directly in browser (localhost:9010/....)

We did our monthly Windows Update yesterday... and since then, those Webapps are not accessible anymore from other workstations, which are in the same network

side notes:

we are running a mssql server on the same machine on the default port, which can be accessed without any problems.

when having WireShark running/listening to the VirtualMachine's IP/Port on the physical Host, we can access the WebApp from the PhysicalHost. As soon as we stop listening, access is not possible anymore.

Does anyone have a clue where to search for the cause?

Don't hesitate to ask for further details and background information. I will provide them...

Answer (score 0):

finally - after some further trial and error - we uninstalled Symantec Protection Tools from the physical host, and after that all services were accessible again. (deactivation was not enough)

thanks for your efforts.